# Count up/down within a specific number range using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm sure this must've been asked before, but I couldn't find anything like that, sorry.

Let's say I have a list of numbers `[1..24]`:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
```

I want to make a function that accepts two integers: `mynum` which is a number in the list and `modifier`. It will then find `mynum` in the list and then cycle through the list `modifier` number of positions (right if positive, left if negative). If it reaches the end of the list, it will loop to the other side.

What I want now is to basically shift the number `mynum` based on the input, within the list.

Example:

```
shift_function(2, 1)   # returns 3
shift_function(23, 3)  # returns 2
shift_function(4, -8)  # returns 20
shift_function(15, 51) # returns 18
```

How can I cycle through the ends of a list like this?

I thought of using the `time` module to get a time with `mynum` as current hour and then add/subtract `modifier` hours to it. This will work with my `[1..24]` range but I'm looking for a more general solution to this what seems to be a simple problem.

**Edit:** To clearify further, I simply want to count through a list of numbers. If the end is reached, start over from the beginning, same backwards.

**Edit2:** I don't know how much more clear I have to be. Imagine you have big numbers on your desk: 3,4,5,6,7. And then you start at the 5 and take `modifier` steps to the right, let's say 3 steps. So you count: "six, seven, three", starting over from the beginning again. If `modifier` is negative, you count backwards. E.g. with `-4` you count: "four, three, seven, six".

I can't see how this is so hard to get. Seems like a very simple and common problem to me.

Comment: How exactly 4 and -8 become 20?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to achieve. I have a fixed number range as in my example and I want to count within that list. If it reached the beginning of the list it should move to the end and vice versa.

Comment: We're not sure what your "shift" operation means, nor how your function produces the expected output from the given parameters.  From what you've said, I expect that this is a direct application of basic number theory and the modulus (%) operator.

Comment: @Prune I thought I was clear enough. I just want to count through a list of numbers. If the end is reached, start over from the beginning. Same backwards.

Comment: Can you please explain downvotes when leaving them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this function does what you want:

```
def shift_function(n, shift):
   return numbers[(numbers.index(n) + shift) % len(numbers)]
```

Comment: Perfect. This does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `numpy`, using [`np.roll`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html). Just be aware that the negative is actually inverse relative to what you want, so you can use `-modifier` instead:

```
import numpy as np

numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]

mynum = 4
modifier = -8

>>> np.roll(numbers,-modifier)[numbers.index(mynum)]
20

mynum = 15
modifier = 51

>>> np.roll(numbers,-modifier)[numbers.index(mynum)]
18
```

Comment: This works for me, but I prefer DYZ's solution as it doesn't rely on another module.

Comment: Makes sense, @DYZ's solution is pretty nifty! I'll leave this as an alternative in any case.

Comment: You can also roll a `collections.deque` if you don't want to pull in numpy.